# Type for dynamic object/record in class

Tags: typescript, types

I want to be able to have the proper type of object that I have the ability to modify (append props) dynamically. Here's a sample:

```js
class Services {
  items = {};
  
  add(key, value) {
    this.items[key] = value;
  }
}

const services = new Services();
services.add('test', new TestService()); // this might be another class/function/object
services.test; // I'd like to have both services and services.test typed
```

I was able to make `add` accept dynamic properties using generics easily. The thing I'm struggling with is `items` type. Having it as an object or Record is explicitly inferring `any` for the values.

I've stumbled upon Lookup Types, which is easy to get within a function by passing the object to work upon. But I am unsure how to deal with it when statically defined.

Thanks upfront!

p.s. @jcalz are you around? :P

Comment: It kinda depends on what you want: if the things in items are all the same type you can say `public items: Record<string, ThatType> = {};` how "dynamic" are these things being added?

Comment: How would `services.test` work?  Wouldn't that be `services.items.test`?

Comment: Assuming `services.items.test` and not `services.test`, [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wj0g2m) is the best I can imagine doing. TS isn't really geared toward mutating types like this, and depending on the use case it might not work for you.  Does that fully address the question? If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Sorry, I'm again trying to simplify something already working, and I've made a mistake in order to explain what my issue was. Ideally, I'd like to use `services.serviceName` (`test` in the example above) in order to access it. So `services` should be something like `add method + all added services` :) I've added the items object in order to figure out how to type it. Not sure how to work on the class itself

Comment: I was going to propose [similar solution](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEkoGdnwComQFwMohgDcBLMBAb3gF8AoGpVefI0rAHgEl4BeecqgHx868RAHsAdjhgBXMNjEwAFAAcZAIwil4xbCAC2yAFzwOASj7UR8KMGBsA0vBAAPPROBoA1iACeYgDMbCV8AGngANQElH18TB3DCKAgZEBMIsxMUZAJsNGwAC2I0YvhC0oAyJgISMmQ2ACVwRXsEyIEhYVFRJXLkADpdAzQUYN8zAG1YgF0eeCSUkABuGlFaWnpJHHgcljqTZlqsOYkQAHdqvawlfjMVml2jgdtgJQByPRw38NOLzBxDqwlGY7vAAPRgspFND6YgAcwK2Hg6gQUAkYkKBEQ0FQYICMgk8mIkjBYnUACtwNgHjVWAMhoZ+p9sEtwZCOG9gPAtD4ymJ4AUoIQEOoMQUdrS6sEuY86UysEjsL4VCBgDQgA) but adding it as comment as it's somewhat similar to @jcalz's

Comment: So then please [edit] the code to be a [mre].  Your implementation just assigns the property to `items` and not to the instance itself.  Why not get rid of `items` and just write `this[key] = value`?  Once you do that, then re-read my last comment substituting [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WG81Kw) and let me know how to proceed.

Comment: I can see those two working as I'd expect. Thanks for providing both solutions (with and without items) - it was pretty helpful. Can any of you explain what `assert this is this` is in their answers, please? I am also unsure why `Exclude` would work with the `Record` (I guess it'll be `never` if it's `added`, and a Record can't have a key of `neve`?)
I'd send much appreciation and beer if you know how to make this work in a JSDoc scenario, where I have just a simple class :rofl:

Comment: I don't need beer but I would love it if you'd [edit] your question to be a [mre] of what you're asking, without `items`. The way it is now is just distracting and would require any answer fix the implementation which isn't your question, I think.   Then there's the JSDoc thing; if you have a need for JSDoc then it should be mentioned directly in the question and possibly even tagged as such, since by default "typescript" means ".ts" files.  I'll wait until I see a final version of the question before proceeding with an answer.

Comment: @AndreyPopov just read about the docs for *Assertion Functions* and take a look how the [type of services changes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEkoGdnwComQFwMohgDcBLMBAb3gF8AoGpVefI0rAHgEl4BeecqgHx868RAHsAdjhgBXMNjEwAFAAcZAIwil4xbCAC2yAFzwOASj7UR8KMGBsA0vBAAPPROBoA1iACeYgDMbCV8AGngANQElH18TB3DCKAgZEBMIsxMUZAJsNGwAC2I0YqYCEjJkTngAMngAJXBFewTIgSFyGlFRAHl1ACtwbAA6UADiCRAABRgxFVzfJULi4d0DNBRTWoammBbwqPDY8MoklIQqMwBuLqtaekkceByWSpNmCqweeEmAdzLXlglPxrnQXp9kMNbMAlAByPQ4WHhP4YLB4cqsJRmUEAehx3XgAD0APw0cGsSFrQzDBHYG54gkkmhAA)

Comment: @jcalz you don't have to be that extremely strict ;) I'll indeed edit my post, not sure how that's related to your answer. I've already said I found what I was looking for, and learning how that works was my top priority. Solving specific issues would be too narrow to find answers for and is not stated in the question. Cheers!